# Getting the KeyID from the "parent" repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a Repeater - in an Ajax Accordion - in the ItemTemplate of an outer repeater.

To picture it better, it is a Blog with comments under each post, but these comments are collapsed in the Accordion.

I'm able to see the Repeater nested inside the accordion by using OnItemDataBound, finding the Accordion in the outer repeater, and the inner repeater by using the Accordion.FindControl.  So far, so good.

What's happening, however, is that ALL comments are being bound, rather than just the comments that are specific to that blog post.  I need to be able to pass the KeyID to the inner nested Repeater so that I can select comments relevant to each Blog post where ID = KeyID.

I'm guessing the ID is going to be somehow tied to the RepeaterItemEventArgs, but I don't know how that happens, or how to determine which blog KeyID I'm working with.

```
    protected void BindComments(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            AjaxControlToolkit.Accordion myCommentsAccordion = (AjaxControlToolkit.Accordion)e.Item.FindControl("CommentsAccordion");
            Repeater myCommentRepeater = (Repeater)myCommentsAccordion.FindControl("CommentsRepeater");

            Utility myUtility = new Utility();
            SqlConnection myConn = myUtility.GetConnection();
            string myCommandText = "select [CommentID],[ShadeID],[Commenter],[CommentDate],[Comment] from [Comments] where ShadeID = " + ???? + " order by CommentDate DESC";
```

If more info would be helpful, please let me know.  I'm not sure what is helpful and what just clutters up the question.

UPDATE - aspx as requested below:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestShades.aspx.cs" Inherits="DisciplesWalk.TestShades" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content" runat="server">
<asp:Image ImageAlign= "Middle" ID="ShadesBanner" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Banners/Shades.jpg" />
<asp:Label ID="myErrorLabel" runat="Server"  CssClass="failureNotification"></asp:Label>
    <div id="ShadesDiv" class="ShadesDiv">
    <asp:Repeater ID="ShadesRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="BindComments">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <!-- top level repeater element template here -->
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="ShadeDate" CssClass="ShadeDate" runat="server" Width="100%" Text='<%# Bind("ShadeDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
            <span class="notehead">
            <asp:Label ID="ShadeTitle" CssClass="ShadeHeading" runat="server" Width="100%" Text='<%# Bind("ShadeTitle")%>'></asp:Label>
            </span>
            <br /><br />
            <span>
            <img alt="" src="Images/shades/<%# Eval("ShadeImage") %>"  style = "width:200px; padding-right:9px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:3px; float:left;" />
            <%# Eval("ShadeBody") %>
            </span>
            <br />
            <AjaxToolkit:Accordion ID="CommentsAccordion" runat="server"
            SelectedIndex="-1"
            CssClass="accordion"
            HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader"
            HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeaderSelected"
            ContentCssClass="accordionContent"
            AutoSize="None"
            FadeTransitions="true"
            TransitionDuration="250"
            FramesPerSecond="40"
            RequireOpenedPane="false"
            SuppressHeaderPostbacks="true">
            <Panes>
                <AjaxToolkit:AccordionPane runat="server" ID="OverviewPane">
                    <Header>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Comments</Header>
                    <Content>
                        <div style="overflow-y:scroll;height:450px"> 
                            <asp:Repeater ID="CommentsRepeater" runat="server">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <br />
                                    <span>
                                    <asp:Label ID="CommenterLabel" runat="server" Width="100%" Text='<%# Eval("Commenter")%>'></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Width="100%" Text='<%# Eval("CommentDate")%>'></asp:Label>
                                    </span>
                                    <span>
                                    <asp:Label ID="CommentBody" runat="server" Width="100%" Text='<%# Eval("Comment")%>'></asp:Label>
                                    </span>
                                    <br />
                                    <hr class="HRSeperator" />
                                    <br /><br />
                                </ItemTemplate> 
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </div>
                    </Content>
                </AjaxToolkit:AccordionPane>
            </Panes>
        </AjaxToolkit:Accordion>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <SeparatorTemplate>
            <br />
            <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/separator.jpg" ImageAlign="Middle" />
            <br /><br />
        </SeparatorTemplate> 
    </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
    <asp:Table ID="AddCommentTable" runat="server" CellPadding="12" cellspacing="0" width="100%" Visible="false">
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell  HorizontalAlign="Left">
                <br />
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="AddCommenterLabel" Text="Name:" Visible="True"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="CommenterTextBox" runat="server" Width="25%"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="CommentLabel" Text="Your comment:" Visible="True"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="CommentTextBox" runat="server" Width="90%"></asp:TextBox>
                <br /><br />
                <asp:Button ID="AddCommentButton" runat="server" Text="Submit Comment" onclick="AddCommentButton_Click" />
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: could you please paste your .aspx file. This way it will me more clear how repeater controls are nested.

Comment: @UrošGoljat You bet. I'll do that now.

Comment: i have posted my suggested solution in a separate answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this way:

In .aspx file above the definition of

```
<AjaxToolkit:Accordion ID="CommentsAccordion" runat="server"
```

put this line

```
<asp:Label ID="lblShadeID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ShadeID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
```

and then use this code for `BindComments` method:

```
protected void BindComments(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        AjaxControlToolkit.Accordion myCommentsAccordion = (AjaxControlToolkit.Accordion)e.Item.FindControl("CommentsAccordion");
        Repeater myCommentRepeater = (Repeater)myCommentsAccordion.FindControl("CommentsRepeater");

        var label = e.Item.FindControl("lblShadeID") as Label;
        int shadeId = Convert.ToInt32(label.Text);

        Utility myUtility = new Utility();
        SqlConnection myConn = myUtility.GetConnection();
        string myCommandText = "select [CommentID],[ShadeID],[Commenter],[CommentDate],[Comment] from [Comments] where ShadeID = @shadeId order by CommentDate DESC";
        // set command parameter named @shadeId to the value of shadeId, execute the query and bind data to myCommentRepeater
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Uros

Comment: That's a fabulous solution, and I am indeed getting the ID now.  An interesting thing, however, is that I'm getting only the odd numbers - 27,25,23.  So, this leads me to believe that the "AlternatingTemplate" is required???  I'll play with it and see.  I believe your solution has given me what I need to get where I want to go.  I love this forum!!  So helpful.